# nsurlconnection server needed special settings?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurl

I wanted to know if the server should have special setting to work with nsurlconnections? When I tried creating a connection and authentication. I don't get any error or warning but it does not connected.

Could any one please clarify me on this.

Thanks

Edit: Here is the code I currently use

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"loginURl"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0]; 
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self]; 
    [webView1 scalesPageToFit]; 
    if (theConnection) { 
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain]; 
    } else { 
        NSLog(@"Connection Failed"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You may want to provide more info and accept more answers to get a reply

Comment: Can you tell me what details you want so that I can tell u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement NSURLConnection delegate method :

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
           NSLog("Connection successful");
   }
```

This will log to the console with connection successful string. See the response data, you may find some information about the connection in it.

Comment: I did implement this method. I get it successful. In the didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response, the server always responds with the same url which I am using to connect to server.

Comment: Then thats fine, in the server have you implemented anything to respond when the url is loaded somewhere ?

Comment: The url which I am working is a web page. it works fine in the browser and now I am trying to use the same url and work with nsurlconnection.

Answer (score 1):

No, your server does not need any special config. A `NSURLConnection` uses just simple HTTP-Requests.

For the authentication: You need to implement the needed delegate methods for authentication yourself. Also check if you are connectiong through SSL and also implement the required delegate methods for this.

**Edit**: Heres a piece from one of my Apps that use HTTP auth. I discovered that you also need to return YES for the NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic in the `canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:` method, otherwise it wont work.

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust] || [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic];
}
```

Comment: I am connecting using https. Server has problem with certificate so I am implementing canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace and also didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge and other related methods. But I am not able to authenticate by server or shows up any error. Can you please tell what could be the problem.

Comment: Do you have implemented the delegate methods of NSURLConnection? This page in the docs provides a complete overview of how to implement loading of URLs -> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Comment: You need to append the received data to receivedData in the didReceiveData:(NSData *)data method. Do all your logs get printed to the console?

Comment: All my logs are getting printed. My problem is in - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveData:(NSData *)data is responding with the html data of the page and -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response with the same url I am using to contact. it is not authenticating and letting me go to next page. I followed the same url you suggested when coding the nsurlconnection.

Comment: I've looked into some code from one of my Apps that uses HTTP auth, see my edit for the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for project

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    parserObject = [NSXML_Parser alloc];// parser initialization
    composerObject = [URLComposer alloc];// composer creation
    [composerObject init_URLComposer];//composer initialization

    [self.view addSubview:logIn_View];
    [webView1 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"loginURl"]]];
    NSMutableData * receivedData = [NSMutableData alloc];
    NSLog(@"Starting the url conn");
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"loginURl"]                   
                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy                             
                                            timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    [webView1 scalesPageToFit];
    if (theConnection) {

        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Connection Failed");
        // Inform the user that the connection failed.
    }
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    NSURLRequest *urlreq =  [webView request];
    NSURL *req = [urlreq URL];
    NSURL *connectingUrl = [NSURL URLWithString: @"loginURl"];
    Boolean error1 = [req isEqual:errorUrl];// use string size to identify the error in url
    Boolean error2 = [req isEqual:connectingUrl];
    if (error1) {
        //[self.view addSubview:displayObj];
    }
    else if(error2) {

    }
    else {
        NSString *session_ID = [str_Url substringFromIndex:strLen];
        XMLDataFromServer = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:testing_Url_String]]; 
        [self logIn_Button_Click];
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {

}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSURLConnection Methods
#pragma mark -

- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    NSLog(@"canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace");
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0){
        NSLog(@"Auth tried");
        NSURLCredential *credentials = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"userName" password:@"password" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];

        [[challenge sender] useCredential:credentials forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Auth failed");
    }    
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse: %@\n",[[response URL] absoluteString]);
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    //NSLog(@"Did receive data: %@",data);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    NSLog(@"Error is:%@",error);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn
{

    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
}
```

Comment: I dont know how to format code in stackoverflow. I tried but  I could not. Sorry for troubling you.